# Windows azure free tier background processing?

Tags: asp.net, windows, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, background-process

I'm trying out Windows Azure free trial - as I understand, you can host up to 10 websites on the free account.

My question is: is there any way of hosting a website along with some kind of background processing or scheduled task with the free account on Azure? I'm almost sure that it's not because Web roles support that and not Web sites.

Is there any other alternative to host an ASP.NET MVC website with some kind of background processing on Azure for free? Everything would be purely for educational or personal purposes.

Comment: What kind of background processing? Can't you use TPL and async/await?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free sites in Windows Azure Web Sites can technically run some background operations because you can spin up a background thread in the application start up; however, there are a several issues with this approach:

Idle sites will be shut down.  This means that if the site isn't seeing a lot of traffic the process can be shut down.  I'm not sure that the background processing would keep it alive, or even if it did how reliable that would be kicking off.  It will depend heavily on the type of background processing I would think.

The web sites at the free level have CPU and memory quotas.  Running something a lot in the background may cause you to hit these quota more often than if the site is more idle.  Hitting the quota will shut down the site until a specific time period has past.  Be very aware of these quotas if you are using the free or shared levels.  If you were planning to have this background processing working a queue for instance this likely won't work out well.

You could use something like the free level of the [Scheduler in the Windows Store](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/store/service/?id=53765649-ba4b-4fe2-a834-21b334b551e2) app to kick off some work by having it call in to your web site and asynchronously kick off the back ground work.  This might work and avoid the CPU quota if the amount of background work is pretty small and is completed quickly and with little resources used.  Note that there is also a scheduler available with Mobile Services.  For educational purposes this may just fine.

Don't forget that with the free trial you get $200 worth of Azure for 30 days.  If you are really just trying things out you can easily spin up full cloud services, VMs or even shared web sites during the trial.  If you shut them down when not actively working on them the $200 can give you a decent amount of time to try things out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll give the Scheduler you mentioned a try. I know that you get $200 of Azure for 1 month but I'd like to continue using the website I make occasionally so there wouldn't be any point in spending much on it after this month passes.